# coefficient interpretation dummy variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

My model is: Wage=B0+B1married+B2fem+B3married*fem+...+e

To interpret the married variable, which is a dummy, I make the difference from the expected values and get: B1 +B3fem. How to interpret this value?

Answer (score 1):

The "effect" of marriage from your model depends on gender.

If you are married *male*, that is associated with B1 more wages (compared to an unmarried male).

If you are a married *female*, that is associated with B1 + B3*1 = B1 + B3 more wages (compared to an unmarried lady).

If B1 is positive and B3 is negative, then the marriage premium for women is lower than for men. If B3 is also very large, the premium becomes a penalty.